# Use partial attributes from namedtuple for comparison

Tags: python-3.x, list, namedtuple

I have a namedtuple with fields (x, y, z) where z is optional.

Comparison operators like 'in' considers all fields for comparison

```
from collections import namedtuple


p = namedtuple('p' , ('x' ,'y', 'z'), defaults = (None,) * 3)

a = p(1,2, 0)
b = p(2,1)

co_ord_list = [a,b]

c = p(1,2)
if c in co_ord_list :
    print(f"Already Exists")
else :
    co_ord_list.append(c)

print(co_ord_list)
```

I don't want 'c' to be added to list when it's matching 'x' and 'y' is already present.

Actual output : [p(x=1, y=2, z=0), p(x=2, y=1, z=None), p(x=1, y=2, z=None)]

Expected output : Already Exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it quite easily by extending named tuple and overriding method `__eq__`

```
class p(namedtuple('p' , ('x' ,'y', 'z'), defaults = (None,) * 3)):

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, self.__class__) and self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((x, y))

a = p(1,2, 0)
b = p(2,1)

co_ord_list = [a,b]

c = p(1,2)
if c in co_ord_list :
    print(f"Already Exists")
else :
    co_ord_list.append(c)

print(co_ord_list)
```

Output:

```
Already Exists
[p(x=1, y=2, z=0), p(x=2, y=1, z=None)]
```

Your example would work without defining your own `hash` function but it is a good practice because `a == b` implies `hash(a) == hash(b)`. It would also work without `isinstance(other, self.__class__)` in the condition in `__eq__` method but this prevents from `AttributeError` when comparing objects of different types which would happen if your list `co_ord_list` also contained objects of some other type.

Comment: 'defaults' before python 3.7 are done quite differently. I am getting the error "TypeError: namedtuple() got an unexpected keyword argument 'defaults'". Is there any known workaround for this error?